# Incremental model without updating changed records

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I want to build a dbt model that returns the minimum timestamp for each `user_id`.
My source table is a versioning table with several billion rows. Hence, I want to build it as an incremental model.
In source data, `version_id` is unique and each `user_id` can have several records. Here is what it looks like:

```
with t1 (version_id, user_id, updated_at, is_activated) as (
        select * from values
        (1, 'a', '2022-12-01'::timestamp, true)
      , (2, 'b', '2022-12-02'::timestamp, true)
      , (2, 'b', '2022-12-03'::timestamp, false)
   --   , (1, 'a', '2022-12-03'::timestamp, true)
)
select * from t1
```

When a `user_id` gets another row (e.g. 4th row) with a newer time, I don't want dbt to update the old row as the first row has the minimum timestamp.
How to ensure the new rows do not update all the old ones based on the min timestamp per `user_id`?

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='version_id'
    )
}}
    WITH filtered AS (
    
        SELECT
            version_id
            , user_id
            , updated_at
        FROM {{ ref('versions') }}
    
        WHERE is_activated = TRUE
            {% if is_incremental() %}
                AND updated_at > (SELECT MAX(this.updated_at) FROM {{ this }} AS this)
            {% endif %}
    
        QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY updated_at) = 1
    )
    
    SELECT * FROM filtered
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you want. Can you include a table of the desired output, given your input? Also, your example data doesn't match the description of the table ("in source data, `version_id` is unique")

Comment: I'm a bit confused as well. I would recommend putting more sample data and desired output as @tconbeer mentioned. One thing for sure is your `unique_key` is incorrect. You need to include the `user_id` as well.